# Create new dataframes from each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe which consists of monthly timeseries data for various countries

I would like to split the dataframe into new dataframes for each country;

Original dataframe;

```
            France  Spain  Netherlands China
01/01/2018   3       3      4            6
01/02/2018   7       5      7            5
.
.
.
01/01/2022   7      8       8            9
```

And then ideally afterwards I would have new dataframes per country..?

eg;

```
            France  
01/01/2018   3       
01/02/2018   7       
.
.
.
01/01/2022   7     


            Spain
01/01/2018   3       
01/02/2018   5       
.
.
.
01/01/2022   8
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `dfs = [df[[col]] for col in df.columns]`?

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension for list of DataFrames:

```
dfs = [df[[col]] for col in df]
```

Then processing is possible in loop:

```
out = []
for x in dfs:
    #some processing
    #x = x + 1
    out.append(x)
```

If need one unpivoted DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.melt(ignore_index=False)
```

Comment: Does this not make a list rather than new dataframes?

Comment: @spcol - yes, it create both - list of DataFrames

Comment: @spcol what did you expect? You wanted n new dataframes.

Comment: @timgeb I was just hoping to be able to then manipulate the dataframes afterwards. I'm not sure how to pull dataframes from the list to then work with them

Comment: @spcol you don't know how to access items in a list? Please work through the official Python tutorial before using pandas.

Comment: @spcol - can you be more specific about processing?